# Windows command to delete all files except the specified list of files which may contain spaces in their names

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a folder contains a list of files. I am using following command to delete all the files except the required files. If there is a file with spaces in the name then following command is failing. Say "File Name with space.txt" or "File 1.txt"

```
for /f %F in ('dir /b /a-d ^| findstr /vile "file1 file2 file3"') do del "%F"
```

I tried putting the file names in "" but no success.

Comment: Is DOS a requirement? Powershell or even WSL will make your life much easier.

Comment: Are you really still using "DOS" or are you referring to the command line in Windows (which has nothing to do with MS-DOS)

Comment: @kabanus I am referring to command line in windows.   Even I can use Powershell if required.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name well, it does share many of the basic commands. Not sure the fact it is just a look alike matters to the specific question.

Comment: @kabanus: From the `dos` tag info: "*DO NOT USE THIS TAG FOR QUESTIONS ABOUT THE WINDOWS COMMAND PROMPT!*" (the `for` loop shown in the question wouldn't even run in "DOS")

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ah, I see your point now, thanks.

Comment: Two options for you.  Use  the `/G` option and put the file names in a file.  Or use `/C` option for each file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options with the `FINDSTR` command to accomplish this.

The first is to list each file individually with the `/C` option.

```
for /f "delims=" %F in ('dir /b /a-d ^| findstr /V /I /L /E /C:"file1" /C:"file2" /C:"file3"') do del "%F"
```

The other option is put all your search strings in a file, one on each line and use the /G option.

```
for /f "delims=" %F in ('dir /b /a-d ^| findstr /V /I /L /E /G:"search.txt"') do del "%F"
```

Comment: The 1st option worked for me. I have not tried 2nd option as this requires separate file creation.